# fastapi installation, Cargo installation error

Tags: installation, rust-cargo, fastapi

I used pip install fastapi[all]

[image]

I added cargo to path,

[image]

Comment: For the future, please don't take pictures of text because the search doesn't work with them, and they might be difficult to read for someone.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem comes from **orjson**, it is a Rust based library and seems like you have done something wrong with your Package manager **(Cargo)**.

Consider **Container**izing your working environment, or you can install fastapi without `[all]` option. By doing that, `pip` will not install orjson.